# Geometry Node Raycast doesn't work properly

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to repeat the tutorial of CrossMind Studio. In his [Raycast tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NphEsVBP-wQ&list=PLgO2ChD7acqHzccBuhAGw8dTPLnR1E3QB&index=34) at 29:53 he shows how to raycast curves from plane to the surface of a character. But when I try to repeat it all curves are raycasting to the origin of this character. I can't move the origin to the character because he is moving. But it doesn't matter because all the curves are going to one point.
[image]

Here are the nodes I am using for this effect
[image]

I can't paste here the nodes from tutorial because they are not at 1 screen. But here is the image how it must look like

[image]

I tried also to assign Geometry Nodes to different object (to plane and not to the character) but it gives me the same result.
[image]

Nodes for this pic:
[image]

I tried to ask the author, but he has too much comments at his channel to answer all of them. Maybe somebody could help me with this issue? Some tips? Want to end this study project. I will leave the link to the [project here](https://mega.nz/file/LZNDWbAR#0ZdAf5BLJIxkNPsl99ZoGjna7_S3eUcgNr0s6VWLVpo) .

Thanks to all of you.

Update: I played with Ray Direction and moved a character and it partially works... I have curves on my character but also curves that are going to the origin. How to reduce them?
[image]

Also if I move the character, curves are raycasting from wrong curves.
[image]

Comment: There is a warning on your Ray Cast node. If you hover over it, what does it say?

Comment: @RobinBetts 
Instances in input geometry are ignored. 
Input geometry has unsupported type: Curve.

Comment: I solved it. I changed the man with sphere and moved geonodes to different plane, when I played with the origin of the plane from which curves are raycasting - everything started to work, then I changed the spere with a character. It took me too much time... but I learned a lot.